# Tomcat API Request Timeout background processing

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, timeout

I have a scenario where I am running a tomcat web server with spring boot. I have an API which is calling a downstream API in a for loop. The end-to-end execution of the API takes about 120s. The API is calling a downstream API which updates a database. I am trying to understand what will happen to the thread that is calling these downstream APIs if the server times out the request in 60s.

Is it expected that the thread calling the downstream APIs will asynchronously complete despite the request timing out (provided the OS has enough system resources)?

For example, I have 10000 requests/sec to an API for different users to generate an invoice and pay the invoice. The requests start timing out at 60s. Assuming there is write traffic for just a period of time of 30 mins or so. If the user refreshes the page after a period of time and calls a GET API would that reflect the writes that were executed as part of the 10000 requests? Or do the threads get cancelled in a way where the writes would not complete? The invoice gets stored only at the very last step of the API call which happens after about 110-120s, and the request is expected to timeout at 60s.